# get select value from a drop with angulars reads error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to get the selected value from a drop down list with angularjs. When I select the value I get this error `angular.min.js:108 TypeError: Cannot read property 'ftype' of undefined`

HTML

```
<select name="select" ng-model="queryBy" ng-change="get_search_value(item)">
  <option ng-repeat="item in filter"  value="{{item.ftype}}">{{item.ftype}}</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$scope.search_type='';
  $scope.filter = [       
    { id: 1, ftype: "Complaint Type"},
    { id: 2, ftype: "Region" },
    { id: 3, ftype: "District"},
 ];

  $scope.get_search_value=function(item){
$scope.search_type=item.ftype;
alert(item.ftype)

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood AngularJS... It does all of this for you. You don't need to update a separate value and you don't need a change event to do this for you.

Here is what I think you're trying to achieve:

**HTML**

```
<select name="select" ng-model="queryBy">
  <option ng-repeat="item in filter" value="{{item.ftype}}">{{item.ftype}}</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.filter = [       
  { id: 1, ftype: "Complaint Type"},
  { id: 2, ftype: "Region" },
  { id: 3, ftype: "District"}
];

// you can access the selected value by using $scope.queryBy
```

That's right, just using `$scope.queryBy` (or just `queryBy` in your HTML) will give you the value of the selected option. As tymeJV mentioned, you can also use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of ngRepeat for your options. I'd also recommend looking into using [ngBind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) instead of curly braces where you can, it will avoid the expression itself flashing before being evaluated.

Comment: But where is the function

Comment: It is not needed, AngularJS automatically updates `$scope.queryBy` to match the selected option's value. If you need to do other things on change, then you can add it back in, but it is not needed to update the search type.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is `item` is invisible on the level of `<select>`. Whatever is in the `<option>`(so, the 'item') should be saved in the `ng-model` value, which is `queryBy`. Why are you passing `item` to the `get_search_value`? Try acessing the `queryBy` in the `get_search_value` function instead

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `ngOptions` - your `item` is inaccessible the way you currently have it. Here's a quick refactor that should work: